# Error while executing nodejs

Tags: node.js, bash

I am new to node.js when I was trying to execute any program, I get this error.

> bash: node: command not found

Comment: How did you install nodejs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current directory is not included with the location of node executable. You have two options here:

1. Go to location of the node you installed and then try the programs.
2. Export the path of the node you installed into the current location of your path. The following is the command export PATH=[your installed node location path]:$PATH